# Why col-md not working on inside card in bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Please note that I am a developer, not a designer.

I need to separate card div for two columns in desktop mode. I mean "This should be in Left Side" should be display on left side and "This should be on right side" should be display on right side.

I use following HTML.

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    Featured
  </div>
  <div class="card-block">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      This should be in Left Side
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      This should be on right side
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to test online here is the jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/uxfjwhpc/1/).

What is my mistake and how to correct it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The classes `col-*` works when they are wrapped under `row` class. You can find the updated code below for `card-block` div. Hope this helps.

```
<div class="card-block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      This should be in Left Side
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      This should be on right side
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row card-block">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      This should be in Left Side
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      This should be on right side
    </div>
</div>
```

This will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with adding Form inside Card in Bootstrap. Here is my implementation.

From the original bootstrap standard form implementation:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
</div>
</form>
```

I need to adjust it to this to work:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
<div class="row">
  <label for="email" class="col-md-2">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control col-md-10" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
</div>  
</form>
```

I need to change **form-group** class to **row** class to make sure form-horizontal class should work fine inside the card of bootstrap.